# jQuery: Target next instance of div

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to target the next instance of a certain div in a click function.
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUEkE/1/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".listings-item").click(function() {
 $('.hidden').next($('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('preview-listing').hide().delay(400).fadeIn("slow"));
 $('#listings-wrap').masonry('reload');
 });

});
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is by clicking on a `.listing-item` will target the next instance of `.hidden` and change the class to show it in the masonry grid. Currently though, on the click, both instances of `.hidden` are being shown and not just the relevant next instance. I can't figure out why this is. I will soon be appending content to this relevant div, but for now I'm just trying to get this to work, which I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function, which returns all the next siblings. If you add a selector to it for the first hidden element then you will get the next hidden element relative to the `div` that is clicked.

Like this:

```
$(this).nextAll('.hidden:first')
```

Which in full use with your example looks like this:

```
$(".listings-item").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').removeClass('hidden').addClass('preview-listing').hide().delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
    $('#listings-wrap').masonry('reload');
});
```

[Here is you example updated](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/wUEkE/6/)